# Wordpress user authentication using other database table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two website one is built in wordpess and other is core php.

1) site1 with core php ( have member table in database)

2) site2 with wordpress (have user table(wordpress default) in database)

Both database have on same server - localhost

****What I need?****

I need login functionality for wordpress website using member table of core php website, not using wordpress default user table.

currently I have created custom template for wordpress login page and I also get authenticated user from member table but issues is how that user set in wordpresss authentication process.

please let me know if it is possible.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

after manual authentication form mmber table if usr successlully authrnticated then call

```
$credentials ['user_login'] = 'example';
$credentials ['user_password'] = 'plaintextpw';
$credentials ['remember'] = true;
wp_signon( $credentials );
```

to login into wordpress after that you can use `wp_logout_url( $redirect );` to logout the user from wordpress and redirect user to other page. hope it will help.

Comment: add some detail description or add a comment instead of answer for the single line.

Comment: I think it only works with WordPress default users table not other database table like members what I need is get member user logged in as wordpress user table.